# Can we fix the position of nodes in Sankey chart

Tags: sankey-diagram

I was trying to create a new Sankey chart, and I found that the position of the nodes are not fixed once I drag drop them.

If I again run the code, the nodes go back to their respective places.

Can we fix the node position so that We donot need to drag the boxes again and again?